# Carrying out Self replication of humanoid to create versions of itself

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, environment

Premise: 
I have a character that is trying to replicate himself into offsprings that will accomplish his task. He is a major character with immense levels of power/energy. My character has to create more avatars of itself and these need to be clones of the character in ideology.

Problem:
He cannot enter the region and accomplish the task and he does not have an army to do it for him. Hence he needs replications. He has no female to mate with. Magic is the last option I would like to take (magic is an option because it is indeed a magical world). I think he may multiply asexually into clones.
However, exact clones will have the same power levels as him and I want them to fly under the radar. Also, clones have the same physical resemblance and would raise suspicion. Hence I need a touch of diversity if possible.

Options I have come up with (u can add your own too):
1. creating bots of itself with the aim of carrying out repetitive instructions over the lifetime. But that would require introduction of technology and amalgamation with living beings.
2. asexually replicating itself and passing down it's genes to the offsprings, hence storing the instructions and intent in the genes itself.
3. Lay eggs.

question:
How to replicate into offsprings that are low energy but and slightly variant in appearance but more or similar to parent in every other sense? Is eggs the only option??

Analysis and doubts:
1. Creating multiple offsprings/clones of itself repetitively impact the father figure in terms of energy remaining to keep on replicating. Maybe introduce a cooling off period?
2. The bots/children need to carry only a specific set of lineage from the father. Is it possible through asexual reproduction to pass on limited genes or lineage? I focus on such limitations because I want offsprings to carry only particular tasks and be low energy than the father.
3. Any precedence in cinema/fiction available to learn from may help.

Edit: I see people saying the question is unclear. 
1. The question I think clearly says to help with replication. 
2. The options are technical inventions like using bots or using asexual reproduction. People also are saying that the fantasy rules are applicable here which are only known to me. Well when I discard eggs it is not a rule, I clearly mentioned I do not like my character to do eggs. When I say cooling-off period, it is not a rule. I clearly ask that is a cooling off period necessary between replicated creatures or not? 
3. I clearly ask if you have seen something like that attempted before in terms of a character replicating itself by itself?.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81225/discussion-on-question-by-mukul-shdev-carrying-out-self-replication-of-humanoid).

Answer (score 2):

With Asexual reproduction, your character will be supplying all of the source DNA for the cloning. This is not as much of an issue as you might think as, DNA encodes for a potential range of characteristics and then environmental features affect how we develop and grow (as well as which genes are activated etc)

Random example: you have the Genes for being a strong, tall, male. Your mother was an alcoholic while pregnant and you ended up being born with stunted growth (for your gene potentiality) and weak muscles. You received no mental of physical stimulation as a child and proceeded to grow up as a tallish gangly kid with bad eyesight and weak core strength etc.

It is the same with your character, he replicates his Genes. Depending on much 'magical' energy he can spare at the time for the replication and growth process, his clone can look very much like himself, possibly a slightly/very less healthy version or maybe even a better version of himself. See one of my [clone questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58132/how-to-get-clones-to-look-identical-to-original) where I was trying to get my clones to look identical!

As for the actual replication process. I wouldn't really go the 'egg' route. Maybe a more a magical incubation period that incorporates the clone material and a womblike environment that can grow to the size of a fully-grown man. So, actually yes, a giant "egg".

I'm imagining a firm jelly type surface with lots of pulsing veintype webbing providing nutrients/magical energy.

- Either he hibernates with the clone material while it grows. This would require him to have the time to 'disappear' for awhile and a really safe location to hide himself in.
- Or he deposits the clone material into some sort of external magical receptacle and then has to expend further time and energy looking after it, like a mother hen. Having to lay hands on it or spread magical juju all over it.

  - He could then suddenly have to decide to "hatch" his clone earlier than expected or he gets detained/delayed and the incubation period is extended for longer than expected and more energy is utilized, or because he was delayed, the egg didn't receive any energy for an extended period and now your clone is a little "less" like him.
  - trial and error could allow him to figure out what sort of energy expenditure to spend to get a desired "result".
- This would result in genetically similar clones being "hatched" that have a range of appearances. They would look like very similar brothers but not necessarily always identical.
- This process would also impact the clones own magical ability. A really well cared for clone-egg could potentially be more powerful than himself, while a less well taken care clone-egg would result in a more squib-type muggle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder if I do not use any mode of asexual reproduction other than him using an egg like hatching mechanism. Because with other modes of asexual replications, the offsprings look like parent, no?? The genetic engineering or selection u have mentioned here would require me to get him a dedicated lab like place and I can do that. Just the fact that you mentioned 'womb like' environment. This has to be an external place, no? Because if I go traditionally, a father figure with a womb would give my character a very different personality 

Comment: @MukulShdev [queen bees](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/71913/26098) create drones from unfertilised material. Technically that could be like your form of asexual reproduction unlike the worker bees which are fertilised. Drones do not look like the queen...even though she was the only source of info. Check out the link, it could also explain why your clones have less magical ability of their own.

Comment: Lol. Well a chicken "egg" is a womblike environment. Sorta. You have the growing chicken embryo (yolk) inside a placenta (eggwhite) inside a chicken shell (external womblike receptacle), incupated, rotated and cared for etc by the mother. You don't really need a lablike space, just someplace that he is certain won't be interferred with. He could use a locked closet etc. I wasn't suggeting he become pregnant or female etc. As for laying the egg...well, he could obtain some of his genetic material and place it with his hands wherever needed. Magical curation ensures a clone is produced from it.